# mySQL - How to prevent a record from being accessed concurrently?

Tags: mysql, concurrency, locking

I am creating records called "sessions" in a database. Users of my app will be able to find a session, then connect to it. I want to ensure that no 2 users will attempt to connect to the same session. My current process is:

1. Search for available sessions that meet the criteria.
2. If found, update the record in the database with the user's information and mark as 'unavailable' so it can not be found in the search process.

My concern is that multiple users could be searching for sessions at the same time, both of which will be told the session is available, then only the last user will get properly connected to the session.

How can I 'lock' the record once it is found in the search so that any concurrent searches will not be able to find it?

Comment: unless it is a very slow query i don't think you will have to worry about that. otherwise you can use [Lock Tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html)

Comment: I actually just found a mysql query called SELECT....FOR UPDATE that I think will do the trick. Researching more information about it now.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need 2 statements? Can't you just run one `UPDATE` without requiring a `SELECT` first?